# For loop in Excel (appling formula to range of cells)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a ledger in which I record expenses made by multiple persons (let's call them A, B, C and D).

The structure is - roughly - the following:

```
COLUMN 1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3  COLUMN4

Date      Amount   Person   Description
```

I would like to track the expenses of each one of these persons. To do that, I have added a fifth column in which there are 4 cells, one for each person.

[image: Here's an image to better clarify things]

Ideally, the formula of each one of these cells should be:

> For all the cells ranging from C1 to C100, check the content of the cell. If the content matches the name of the person, then add the amount of the B cell of the same row to this cell.

I am, however, unsure on how to do this and would appreciate suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for `GEORGE` (in the cell `E4`) may be:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B100, C2:C100, "GEORGE")
```

For other people it will be the same, only change the *last parameter (the name)*:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B100, C2:C100, "DONNIE")
=SUMIFS(B2:B100, C2:C100, "GEORGE")
=SUMIFS(B2:B100, C2:C100, "BARRY")
```

But the **much better approach** is to use *absolute* references for ranges and a *relative* reference to the cell with a name - to be able to *copy the formula* from the cell `E4` to other cells. So write this formula into the cell `E4`:

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$100, $C$2:$C$100, E3)
```

and then simply *copy it to others appropriate cells (i. e. for `DONNIE`, `GEORGE`, etc.).*